# <Xamarin> How to turn off making screenshots (app.Screenshot()) on Test Cloud?

Tags: c#, testing, xamarin, command-line, xamarin-test-cloud

Is there any way to turn off screenshots (app.Screenshot()) on Test Cloud without removing the code?

I want to turn off screenshots on demand, preferably with some command line parameter i.e "testcloud.exe --someparameter".

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to turn off all screenshots, or only certain ones?

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppInitializer` file, you can **remove** `.EnableLocalScreenshots()` for each platform

```
    if (platform == Platform.Android)
    {
        return ConfigureApp.Android
            .EnableLocalScreenshots()
            .StartApp();
    }
```